How to build Playwright from source code and use the codegen feature?
I'm lost and don't know what I should do, or what it is that I don't know
I see that there is code to generate multiple selectors when using codegen, per
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5178#issuecomment-1130731560

You will see at the end that there is a commit #29154. Follow that link: https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/pull/29154/files. Then, go to the main branch (the code was merged)


https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/tree/main
Download the code to build it

https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9015
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/29400
However, I tried installing playwright latest and even the alpha versions but I'm not able to get codegen to generate the multiple selectors. Therefore, I cloned the code that has the fix:
npm run build
npm install -g .
I was basically trying to install the playwright built from the source code globally (https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/tree/main), in hope that I can run codegen, but I wasn't able to.
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance

The comment you linked to doesn't seem to relate to what you're saying about it. I don't see any code in the comment, for example.

Sorry, I hope it's clearer now. I saw that there was code merged to main from the first link's comments.
I then went to main and download the code to build it
https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/tree/main
